# Cannot resolve method 'assertNotThrows' in 'Assertions' in Junit5

Tags: junit, junit5

I have this JUnit4 code which I want to migrate:

```
  @Test(expected = Test.None.class)
  public void test() {
  .....
  }
```

I tried to migrate this code to Junit5 this way:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(ExceptionNotToThrow.class, () -> {
  .....
});
```

But I get:

```
Cannot resolve method 'assertDoesNotThrow(Class<ExceptionNotToThrow>, <lambda expression>)'
```

Do you know how I can migrate this code properly?

Comment: JUnit 4 does not have a class `Assertions`, can you provide the imports for your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `assertDoesNotThrow` without exception class:

```
@Test
void checkCodeDoesNotThrowAnyException() {
    Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
        //do something
    });
}
```